# javascript colision resolving, cicrlces tangled together

Tags: javascript, physics

I read a lot of articles about detecting and resolving collisions but I can't   solve the  particular error that occurs in my "asteroid" game.[codepen link here](http://codepen.io/Michal_Kaleta/pen/QvMaPx).

In my version  asteroids bounce form each other every time they intersect. I included some vector and momentum preservation physics and most of the time it looks ok. But once in a few bounces the asteroids seem to get entangled together and go in the same direction. I checked my formulas and they are ok. The problem might by in "detaching" them on the time of collision  or in checking array of objects collisions algorithm.

I think the second option is possible because I coded simple collision tester including only 2 circles and the error doesn't occur. [tester code](http://codepen.io/Michal_Kaleta/pen/rmNWPr). My collision function is invoked by `foreach` on every asteroid object and goes like this:

```
Asteroid.prototype.check_asteroid_colision = function() {

    var self = asteroids.indexOf(this);

    for (var i = self + 1; i < asteroids.length - 1; i++) {

        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - asteroids[i].x, 2) +
            Math.pow(this.y - asteroids[i].y, 2));
        if (distance <= this.perimeter + asteroids[i].perimeter) {

            ///////////////////////////untangle: not very precise /////////////
            while (distance <= Math.pow((this.perimeter + asteroids[i].perimeter), 2)) {
                asteroids[i].x -= asteroids[i].speedX / 10;
                asteroids[i].y -= asteroids[i].speedY / 10;
                this.x -= this.speedX / 10;
                this.y -= this.speedY / 10;
                distance = Math.pow((this.x - asteroids[i].x), 2) + Math.pow((this.y - asteroids[i].y), 2);
            }
            //////normal//////////normal unit and tangent unit/////////////////////  
            var normal_x = asteroids[i].x - this.x;
            var normal_y = asteroids[i].y - this.y;
            var normalLenSqrt = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(normal_x, 2) + Math.pow(normal_y, 2));
            var un_x = normal_x / normalLenSqrt;
            var un_y = normal_y / normalLenSqrt;
            var ut_x = -un_y;
            var ut_y = un_x;
            ////////////  MASS /////
            var m1 = this.m;
            var m2 = asteroids[i].m;
            //////////////////projections of velocities on norm and tangent//
            var projNorm_1 = this.speedX * un_x + this.speedY * un_y;
            var projNorm_2 = asteroids[i].speedX * un_x + asteroids[i].speedY;
            ////Project on Tangent////////////////////////////////////
            var projTang_1 = this.speedX * ut_x + this.speedY * ut_y;
            var projTang_2 = asteroids[i].speedX * ut_x + asteroids[i].speedY * ut_y;
            //////////VECTOR ADDITION with  MOMENTUM////////////////      

            this.speedXn = un_x * (projNorm_1 * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * projNorm_2) / (m1 + m2);
            this.speedYn = un_y * (projNorm_1 * (m1 - m2) + 2 * m2 * projNorm_2) / (m1 + m2);
            asteroids[i].speedXn = un_x * (projNorm_2 * (m2 - m1) + 2 * m1 * projNorm_1) / (m1 + m2);
            asteroids[i].speedYn = un_y * (projNorm_2 * (m2 - m1) + 2 * m1 * projNorm_1) / (m1 + m2);

            this.speedXt = projTang_1 * ut_x;
            this.speedYt = projTang_1 * ut_y;
            asteroids[i].speedXt = projTang_2 * ut_x;
            asteroids[i].speedYt = projTang_2 * ut_y;
            //////////addd ///////
            this.speedX = this.speedXn + this.speedXt;
            this.speedY = this.speedYn + this.speedYt;
            asteroids[i].speedX = asteroids[i].speedXn + asteroids[i].speedXt;
            asteroids[i].speedY = asteroids[i].speedYn + asteroids[i].speedYt;
            ///////////////////untangle again????//////////////////////////////////////////////
            asteroids[i].x += asteroids[i].speedX;
            asteroids[i].y += asteroids[i].speedY;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;




        }
    }
};
```

Its driving me insane , please help.

Comment: "get entangled"... usually this is caused when a collision of two objects is not completely resolved within one time step, i. e. they are still colliding after handling their collision. A simple fix is to first check whether those objects are actually moving towards each other or whether they are already moving away from each other (indicating that this collision has already been handled).

Comment: I agree with @le_m and suggest you also to use a QuadTree implementation to have an efficient way of only testing asteroids, which are close to each other. This also allows an efficient check of "moving towards each other"

Comment: Usually, these kinds of entanglements come from bad implementation. Smells are: late collision detection (detecting collision after it happened versus before it actually happens), double collision (colliding from A->B and B->A as well), faulty implementation. I suggest you go through a tutorial, and see if your implementation is correcto. Until then, I think most people would feel bad for manually checking your code :)

Comment: i iterate from the element that is indexed +1 from the chcecking element so no double colisions should happen. And indeed i detect colision after it happens but my first step is "untanglement" . I am substracting small amonut of thier velocities in "while" loop as long as thier touching.